# Test status not getting updated on Jira-Zaphyr when running test from Zapi-Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, jira, jira-zephyr

I have Jira including their plugin Zephyr and ZAPI. I am running my code from Jenkins as shown in the video. My code is in Java+TestNG and I have not added a Junit Plugin for Jenkins. My tests runs fine but console output shows:

Build result is SUCCESS
null
Problem parsing JUnit test Results.
Error parsing surefire reports.
Please ensure "Publish JUnit test result report is added" as a post build action
Build step 'Publish test result to Zephyr for JIRA' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

On Jira it still shows Unexecuted.

Comment: I would not trust the zephyr plugins.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your Jenkins build is getting marked as failure is clearly specified in error report which is you haven't added JUnit plugin as post build action. Zephyr plugin uses testcases published by JUnit plugin to execute testcases on Jira.

Add plugin "Publish JUnit test result report" as post-build action and it should work.

This [link](https://plugins.jenkins.io/zephyr-for-jira-test-management) explains how to setup Zephyr for Jira plugin on Jenkins.